# How to run jQuery function from jQuery generated link ( through append() )?

Tags: jquery, function, append

I have a little trouble with jQuery and I hope you can help me. I think it´s quite easy, but I really don´t know :-(

Problem is, that I write some content through jQuery append() function and in this content there is a link, which should run my own function, if pressed.

Example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/5ahkD/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".add").click(function () {
        $("#items").append('<div id="item">\n\
                   <a href="#" class="delete" id="delete">Delete!</a>\n\
                   Some content inside div element...\n\
                   </div>');
    });

    $(".delete").click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });
  });
```

"Add item!" will generate some content with links ("Delete!") and this links should disappear after click. As you can see on the alone bottom link, it´s OK only when this link is not written through append()...

It is almost certainly stupidly easy, but I cannot find any way of getting this work.

Comment: You are only binding to elements with the class "delete" that are *currently* in the DOM, not elements added in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to delegate the event handling to an element that exists during page load. The `.on()` method provided by jQuery does just that.

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
    $(this).hide(); // will  hide the delete
    // $(this).parent().hide(); //will hide the .item
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Live event handlers](http://api.jquery.com/on/). It will work for newly created/added elements

```
$("#items").on("click", ".delete", function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

If you want to actually remove the created row, use:

```
$(this).parent().remove();
```